# How to apply Pandas isocalendar() to a list of dates rather than a single date

Tags: python, pandas, list, date

Is it possible to apply isocalender() to a list of dates? This should be fairly simple, I'm just struggling with the syntax.

I have it working well with a single date but when I try to loop through a list it gives an error

This was the first step, which works for a single date.

```py
# Takes a single date and outputs the week of the year that date is in (24)
dt = datetime.date(2010, 6, 16)
dt.isocalendar()[1]

Out[143]: 24
```

This was my first attempt to use isocalender() with a list of dates. It gave the error: 'list' object has no attribute 'isocalendar'

```py
dt = pd.date_range(pd.datetime.today(), periods=100).tolist() #List of dates
dt.isocalendar()[1]
```

I tried to put it in a for loop but got the same error: 'list' object has no attribute 'isocalendar'

```py
date_list = []
dt = pd.date_range(pd.datetime.today(), periods=100).tolist() #List of dates
for date in dt:
    date_list.append(dt.isocalendar()[1])
```

I'd like to see a list like this:

```py
date                                               week_of_year
Timestamp('2019-09-09 17:16:01.971533', freq='D')   37
Timestamp('2019-09-10 17:16:01.971533', freq='D')   37
Timestamp('2019-09-11 17:16:01.971533', freq='D')   37
…                                                   …
Timestamp('2019-12-16 17:16:01.971533', freq='D')   51
Timestamp('2019-12-17 17:16:01.971533', freq='D')   51
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for-loop you got confused `dt` is a list, and `date` is the element of the list. You can arrange your code like this:

```
date_list = []
dt = pd.date_range(pd.datetime.today(), periods=100).tolist() #List of dates
for date in dt:
    date_list.append(date.isocalendar()[1])
```

Or you can solve your problem in just one line of code, like this:

```
date_list = [date.isocalendar()[1] for date in pd.date_range(pd.datetime.today(), periods=100).tolist()]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your attempt, `dt` is a `list`, so you should call `isocalendar` on its elements, not it itself, so in your loop (where `date` is an element of `dt`), you should have:

```
for date in dt:
    date_list.append(date.isocalendar()[1])
```